# Access smartphone GPS data from javascript

Tags: javascript, gps

Is it possible to directly access smartphone GPS data from javascript in order to get the exact position of user?

By using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( , , options)`

along with

```
const options = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 5000,
    maximumAge: 0
};
```

we get quite accurate coordinates,

but checking at the same time Google Maps we can see that pointers do not center at the same location, coordinates are slighty different

Comment: check this out: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41374/accessing-gps-data-with-javascript-in-real-time

Comment: Also see: [GeolocationCoordinates.accuracy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GeolocationCoordinates/accuracy)